# Extra folder layer being added to href?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to create ajaxy functionality on my site using  `$(this).attr("href")`, but I get a File Not Found error from firefox when I test it. The strange part, however, is the additional folder it added:

Firefox can't find the file at /C:/Websites/website/Articles/Articles/stuff.html.

The folder structure includes only 1 Articles folder with the html files within. I've tried removing the Articles folder from the href element in index.html, but then I get this error:

/C:/Websites/website/stuff.html.

-which is entirely understandable noting that they are, in fact, in the Articles folder.

The entirety of the javascript controlling this segment is here:

```
$(function() {

    if (Modernizr.history) {

        $("#content").on("click", "a", function() {

            _href = $(this).attr("href");
            history.pushState(null, null, _href);
            loadContent(_href);

        });
    } 
});

var $content = $("#content"),
    $el;

$(function loadContent(href) {

    $content.find("#content");
    $content.fadeOut(500, function() {
        $content.hide();
        $content.load(href + " #content", function() {
            $content.fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the relevant part of index.html:

```
<div id="content">
        <a href="Articles/stuff.html">
        <section>
            <div>
                <p>stuff</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        </a>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on where this may come from?

Answer (score 0):

When you removed Articles from the path did you leave the "/"? If so remove that and try again. That slash makes the path relative instead of absolute

Comment: Yeah I did, that's when I get that second error message I noted up above.

Comment: So you tried both href="/stuff.html" and href="stuff.html" and both don't work?

Comment: Yup. When its href="Articles/stuff.html", I get the repeating Articles folder in firefox, when its href="/Articles/stuff.html", It simply won't load anything upon clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to ignore your code, but isolate that core of your question: *"Why does an extra folder appear in the URL?"*  The front-end:

```
<div>
     <a id="Content" href="~/Articles/Content.html">Content</a>
</div>
```

The Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#Content").on('click', function () {
          var url = $(this).attr('href');
          alert(url);
     });
});
```

The output is the proper URL your attempting to navigate.  [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/q02tsa28/) is a Fiddle of the example.  You could try this approach on your system.  It works for me, so I might suggest the `~/Folder/Page.html`.

Hope this helps, let me know.

Comment: I gave it a shot, but I received errors stating that it could't find the `~/Folder/Page.html`. I also tried a variant without the tilde with no luck. It seems as though it only creates this extra folder when `href="Articles/stuff.html"`, it's the strangest thing.

Comment: You should be doing: `~/Articles/stuff.html`

Comment: Tried that as well, but then it returned: Firefox can't find the file at /C:/Websites/website/~/Articles/stuff.html. So would I need to change my folder names for that to work?

Comment: What if you just do `/Articles/stuff.html`?  I feel like your concatenating it weird.

Comment: When I try that, nothing at all happens on a click :/

Comment: I just checked the _href value with an alert, and it actually is getting the correct location, so it must be something in the loadContent function that's screwing with it